# How to enable file sharing in Moodle?

Tags: moodle, file-sharing

With Moodle, when you are the teacher, you can share files with your students.
You can also ask students to upload an exercice on Moodle.

How can you enable file sharing and colaboration between students ?

We have, for instance, to work together on some files likes images and blender files that we would like to work on together.

Some people are using Dropbox, but we need to guarantee the security of files and an integration with Moodle.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already have a look to the [File Sharing Block](http://moodle.org/mod/data/view.php?d=13&rid=1105)? I haven't tried it myself.

Also, unless you plan to write your own block/module, this question should belong to [Super User](https://superuser.com/).